# How many questions have more than 1 million views on this site?

Tags: support, questions

I would like to know that are there any questions with more than 1 million views on this site(the main movies site and not meta), if yes how many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Two

From this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/1422346/top-10-questions-by-viewcount#resultSets)

The only questions with views over 1m are:

- [When did each Horcrux get destroyed in the Harry Potter movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1354/when-did-each-horcrux-get-destroyed-in-the-harry-potter-movies)
- [Where are Frodo, Gandalf and the others going at the end and why?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10037/where-are-frodo-gandalf-and-the-others-going-at-the-end-and-why)